# I defined a subclass of torch.utils.data.IterableDataset, which line of the following loader could have caused the issue and why?

Tags: pytorch, overfitting

The current model is overfitting quickly, i.e., the training error is minimized in a few epochs while the validation error remains high. Suppose training data is sufficient, i.e. self.cohort is set correctly, which line of the following loader could have caused the issue and why?

```
class DataGeneratorBase(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):    
    def __init__(self, cohort, sample_loader):
        'Initialization'
        self.sample_loader = sample_loader  
        self.cohort = cohort
   
    def image_count(self):
        return len(self.cohort)
         
    def load_cache(self):
        'load 1 image with its augmentations till reaching the end'
        if self.cache.empty():
            for _ in range(self.sample_per_load):
                image_id = numpy.random.randint(0,self.image_count())
                images,labels = self.sample_loader.load_image_label_pair(self.cohort[image_id:image_id+1])
                for i in range(0,len(images)):
                    self.cache.put([images[i],labels[i]])
        return True


    def __iter__(self):
        return self
   
    def __next__(self):
        if self.load_cache():
            return self.cache.get()
```